# Is that possible to single sign-on with completely different domains?

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

we have multilingual Drupal 7 site.

> Swedish Domain : www.swedish.com
>
> English Domain : www.english.com

admin/config/regional/language looks like screenshot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

No Domain access is used. I have tried https://www.drupal.org/project/sso_multi_domain but seems there need sub-domains.

Please suggest is there way we can make login working with separate domains which are pointing to same site folder, same database etc

Thanks!

Comment: No that's not possible, cookies can only be shared on the same domain. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies (and search "cross domain cookies" on google and read the top maybe 5 results)

Comment: What you would need to do this is have a central site that authenticates the user and determines if their session is active, then redirects them back to whatever site they were logging in with. That means implementing your own user authentication which routes requests to that site, and that will return a valid token for that user proving they are authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Domain module? I've looked into it a bit, and seems to do what you need (though I myself have not set up my site yet with it, so I'm not positive). According to the documentation:

> The module allows you to share users, content, and configurations across a group of sites such as:
>
> - example.com
> - one.example.com
> - two.example.com
> - my.example.com
> - thisexample.com <-- can use any domain string
> - example.com:3000 <-- treats non-standard ports as unique

https://www.drupal.org/project/domain

Comment: Users, content and configurations? Yes. Sessions? No

Comment: Way too complicated to throw in just for SSO.